# Issue with Date Picker Field Type

Tags: advanced-custom-fields, date, datepicker

While working on a project, I encountered an issue related to the **date picker** field type. Specifically, I am creating a custom field for date selection using a date picker. However, upon selecting a date, it is displayed in an unexpected format as "**20230807**" instead of the desired "**07/08/2023**" in the posts. Surprisingly, when I use the date **time picker**, the date appears in the correct format.

I am seeking assistance from someone who can help me identify and resolve the problem with the date picker field type, ensuring that the selected date is displayed in the expected "dd/mm/yyyy" format when using the date picker in my posts.

Comment: You'll have to check with ACF support (I gather from the question's tags that you're using Advanced Custom Fields). Third-party plugin support is [off topic](/help/on-topic) here.

Comment: Although I won't post an answer because the question is off-topic, I can offer a suggestion: check to make sure in the ACF field settings that the correct return format is selected (you should have 4 options: "d/m/Y", "m/d/Y" "F j, Y", "Ymd").

Comment: If that doesn't change anything, you can always manually convert date formats by using the `DateTime::createFromFormat()` function. Read more [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/php-datetime-createfromformat-function/).